# Where does android studio find this proxy?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proxy, gradle

I am new to android and trying android studio.

> I have imported an existing android project and I see  Failed to sync
>   Gradle project  Error: Unknown host 'company.proxy.com'

In my laptop there is indeed this proxy set for my work but in my home I can connect directly to the internet. My browser somehow does not go over the proxy so internet works but in the android studio preferences in network I see:

> You have the JVM property "https.proxyHost" set to 'company.proxy.com'
>   And although the button No proxy is pressed it seems that android studio tries 
>   to use this proxy for the sync.

So my question is how does it find this proxy and how can I override it?
Also how could I stop this Gradle sync so that I can run the application?
I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

My Gradle proxy settings are located in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties.
I have an empty version when not behind a proxy and the following one elseway:

```
`systemProp.http.proxyHost=<PROXY_HOST>`
`systemProp.http.proxyPort=<PROXY_PORT>`
`systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost`
```

You can set gradle offline from the ide:

File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle ->
Enable offline work